# Using Union in ArcGIS Pro

Tags: arcgis-pro, union

I cannot see how Union is being used; why in this instance and whether it produces the desired results.

I am posting the procedure for some clarity. I don't understand the selection its asking for either; could someone maybe walk me through that as well?

I know I'm blanking on something simple but none of the bosses even understand GIS

Percent Impervious of Managed Drainage Areas

Calculate the % of the managed area covered by impervious surface for each project.
Required Data:
»»
GSI_Projects
»»
GSI_DrainageAreas (only those associated with GSI footprint locations)
»»
Impervious Area

PROCEDURE:

1. Add 2 fields “PercDAImp” and “ImpDAsq” to the GSI_Projects file

**2. Create a union between the GSI_DrainageAreas and the Impervious Surface layer.

3. Add Field “Impervious” to the unioned file
4. Select all rows that intersected both the drainage areas and impervious
5. Calculate Impervious using Field Calculator as “Yes”
6. Switch selection and calculate Impervious as “NO” – clear all selections**
7. Dissolve unioned file by GSI_ID and Impervious
8. Add 2 fields – ImpDAsf and PervDAsf
9. Select all Impervious = Yes and use the Calculate Geometry to calculate the square footage into ImpDAsf
10. Switch selection and use the Calculate Geometry to calculate the square footage in the PervDAsf. Clear all selections
11. Dissolve by GSI_ID summing fields ImpDAsq and PervDAsf and title
    GSI_DrainageAreas_ImperviousTotal
12. Add a field PercImperv
13. Calculate field as [ImpDAsq]/([ImpDAsq]+[PervDAsq])
14. Join the file GSI_DrainageAreas_ImperviousTotal with GSI_Projects by GSI_ID
15. Use the field calculator to transfer the PercImperv as well as the ImpDAsq fields into GSI_Projects.
16. The proportion of impervious area managed will serve as the score for this criteria

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking. Do you not understand what the Union overlay does? Re. the selection (point 4), you can just use the Select By Attributes tool and construct a query that selects FID_GSI_DrainageAreas > -1 and FID_Impervious > -1 to select records that intersected both the drainage areas and impervious.

Comment: Honestly, I have read the description and I don't know why it is being used to determine the percent coverage of impervious surfaces over the GSI Drainage areas. So I did that selection and it doesn't seem to have that result, there are some blatant cases where the Impervious overlaps with the GSI drainages but does not select the layers. Should I use another method to get my results maybe a clip

Comment: No, Union is required to preserve both the inside and outside parts, so that percentage can be calculated.